# Excel Interop: How to copy merged cells value from one excel sheet to another?

Tags: c#, excel, excel-interop

I have 2 excel workbooks having multiple worksheets. I would like to copy the value from one worksheet to another. Example: I need the value of merged cell range 'C10-F10' (It contains the text -  'TestValue) copied into one single cell 'B6' in another worksheet using Excel Interop? I am using the following code snippet but cannot get the 'TestValue' copied in another worksheet. Please advise. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
 Workbook book1 = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Apps\\test\\appname\\filename1.xlsm);
     Worksheet sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book1.Worksheets.get_Item(2);
                    Range from = sheet.Range["C10:F10"];                   
                    Workbook book2 = excel.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Apps\\test\\appname\\filename2.xlsm);
                    Worksheet worksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)book2.Worksheets.get_Item(4);
                   Range to = worksheet.Range["B6"];
                   from.Copy(to);
```

Comment: In a merged cell eg "C10:F10" the value is in the first cell, so copy only the "C10" to "B6"

Comment: I tried but doesn't really do anything. Should the destination cell ( B6) be empty in order to be copied?

Comment: Sorry, now I see c# in Tags, my comment is for excel VBA... but try to read and print the value from "C10" to see if can read the first of merged cells as I can in VBA.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately, I am not sure how to read and print the value? Please advise